# Can't insert row with two FK to database in .NET using Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio

I can't insert row into database. I'm using .NET with Oracle. I can insert rows to another tables but I can't insert to m:n table, that has two FKeys.

```
public static String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO UserBet(bet_id, ticket_id) VALUES(:bet_id, :ticket_id)";

public static int Insert(int ticket_id, int bet_id, OracleDB pDb = null)
{
        OracleDB db;

        if (pDb == null)
        {
            db = new OracleDB();
            db.Connect();
        }
        else
        {
            db = pDb;
        }

        OracleCommand command = db.CreateCommand(SQL_INSERT);

        command.Parameters.Add(":bet_id", 1);
        command.Parameters.Add(":ticket_id", 1);

        int ret = db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);

        if (pDb == null)
        {
            db.Close();
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The table UserBet is:

```
CREATE TABLE userbet 
(
    bet_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ticket_id  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE userbet 
    ADD CONSTRAINT userbet_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY (bet_id, ticket_id);

ALTER TABLE userbet
    ADD CONSTRAINT userbet_bet_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (bet_id) REFERENCES bet (bet_id);

ALTER TABLE userbet
    ADD CONSTRAINT userbet_ticket_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket (ticket_id);
```

This doesn't work and I got no error messages. How I said, other inserts are working just this doesn't. It's M:N table. Any hint please?

EDIT: It turns out that the problem was caused by the constraints.

Comment: I tried it without PK and FK keys and It works. The problem are the constraints.

Comment: If you hard-code valid values in place of the parameters, does the insert work?

Comment: I always advise setting `command.BindByName = true;` when using Oracle. Without that, it binds the parameters ordinally. Even on SO questions where the parameters are added in the same order as they appear in the query, I've seen it fix the problem. No promises here, but it won't hurt since you've given them names.

Comment: If the problem was caused by the constraints, it seems extremely unlikely that you would not get an error message. If your code is (1) not inserting a new row, and (2) not raising an error message, I suggest you add a breakpoint on the line **int ret = db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);** and make sure the code is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a `table` t1 and another `table` t2, where t1.key is a `foreign key` referencing t2, then, to protect data integrity, Oracle enforces the `foreign key` as a constraint, that is, you cannot `insert into` a `table` a record having a `foreign key` pointing to a not existent record. You cannot `update` a `foreign key` to a value that does not exist. You cannot `delete` a record from the main `table` without handling this in some manner in the reference `table`(s). You can define `cascade` as the `on delete` action for instance.

From the above, an exception is `null`. If your field is nullable, then it can be `null`, even though that's certainly not a value for the `primary key` in the referenced `table`. It's logical though, since `null` is the lack of a value and therefore it's not a reference.